# Animate Expander in WPF

Tags: animation, wpf-controls, expander

How to animate the expanded and collapsed actions of a Wpf expander control?

Answer (score 5):

I've found this article on Code Project : [Read Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248112/Templating-WPF-Expander-Control)

The author creates his own SimpleExpander Template, then adds a stretch out animation to it. He even added a nifty rotating arrow to it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a style based on [msdn Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296(v=vs.110).aspx) and the point in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14164245/5615980):

```
 <Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test" 
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

    <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

    <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

    <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

    <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


    <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

    <!--Border colors-->
    <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

    <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

    <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

    <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

    <!--Control-specific resources.-->
    <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

    <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                   EndPoint="0.5,1"
                   StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
              Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
              Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
              Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                   StartPoint="0,0"
                   EndPoint="1,0">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                  Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                  Offset="0.4" />
                <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                  Offset="0.6" />
                <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                  Offset="1" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderToggleButton"
               TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
        CornerRadius="2,0,0,0"
        BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                         StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                    Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                         EndPoint="0,1">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStopCollection>
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                        Offset="0.0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                        Offset="1.0" />
                        </GradientStopCollection>
                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </LinearGradientBrush>

            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                 Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                 Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
              (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                 Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
              (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                 Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderLightColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedArrow">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                    Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandededArrow">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                    Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid>
                <Path x:Name="CollapsedArrow"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z">
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
                    </Path.Fill>
                </Path>
                <Path x:Name="ExpandededArrow"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Visibility="Collapsed"
          Data="M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z">
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
                    </Path.Fill>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="ContentRow" >
                                <RowDefinition.Resources>
                                    <local:MultiplyConverter x:Key="multiplyConverter"/>
                                </RowDefinition.Resources>
                                <RowDefinition.Tag>
                                    <sys:Double>0.0</sys:Double>
                                </RowDefinition.Tag>
                                <RowDefinition.Height>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiplyConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="DesiredSize.Height" ElementName="Content" />
                                        <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </RowDefinition.Height>
                            </RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                       Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                    (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                       Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderLightColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1"
                                 StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                            Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                            Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>

                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                 EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                                Offset="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                                Offset="1.0" />
                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                            </Border.Background>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                          Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <ToggleButton.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                                Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                                Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </ToggleButton.Background>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Content" Grid.Row="1"  BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,2,2">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ContentAreaColorDark}" />
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
                        </Border>

                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>  
    <Expander  Header="Canny" >
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="A" />
            <Button Content="B" />
            <Button Content="C" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>

    <Expander Header="Sobel" >
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="A" />
            <Button Content="B" />
            <Button Content="C" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Header="LoG" >
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="A" />
            <Button Content="B" />
            <Button Content="C" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>

</StackPanel>


</Window>
```

Which requires this converter:

```
public class MultiplyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new GridLength((double)values[0] * (double)values[1], GridUnitType.Pixel);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The main point is to set DoubleAnimation on `ContentRow.Height` in the template. However, you need to use a `MultiBinding` to bind the `To` property of this animation.

Comment: This is a great approach. The issue I'm having is the expanders contain dynamic lists of things and getting it to resize when items are removed from the collections is prooving tricky. Any ideas?