# ActualWidth as value of From WPF animation

Tags: wpf, actualwidth

Why can't I refer to `ActualWidth` as a value from, which I was able to use in code.

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="cmdVibrate" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation From="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},Path=ActualWidth}" By="200" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"></DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
            Mouse over me to shake
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}` will probably be refering to the `DoubleAnimation` (which doesn't have an `ActualWidth` property). Try to find the ancestor `Button` instead

```
From="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}},
               Path=ActualWidth}"
```

**Xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="cmdVibrate" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation From="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                         By="200"
                                         AutoReverse="True"
                                         Duration="0:0:1"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"></DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
        Mouse over me to shake
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```