# Animate double value depending on current state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I would like to use a `DoubleAnimation` to animate a double-`DependencyProperty` on MouseOver depending on it's current value. For the sake of simplicity lets say i want to animate a ListBoxItem to move slightly to the right while i hover my mouse over it and move back when the mouse is removed.

I started out by defining `<DoubleAnimation By="5">` and `<DoubleAnimation By="-5">` in the `EnterActions` and `ExitActions` of my MouseOver-Trigger. This works fine if i hover the mouse over the object long enough, but if i interrupt the first animation by moving the mouse, the second animation will run longer than the first one. Thus after all animations are done, the objects position is slightly off.

I can use `FillBehaviour="Stop"` in the Storyboard to fix the state of my object after all animations are done. However this makes the object snap back into place, which obviously looks quite irritating.

What i would **like** to do is to specify the `To`-Property in the second `DoubleAnimation` to be the original value of my Property. This was calculated initially by a `Converter`, so I tried to bind that Property to the already existing `Converter`. This throws an error due to threading issues (while i was surprised at first, google explained the reason quite well). I even found a post covering this ([WPF animation: binding to the "To" attribute of storyboard animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186933/wpf-animation-binding-to-the-to-attribute-of-storyboard-animation)) and might be able to modify this to fit my situation. However this feels like a "hacky" solution.

**The question:** I feel like i am not thinking straightforward enough anymore. All I want to do is to "move" an object on mouseover and "move" it back afterwards. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If you **do not** specify `To`, then *actual value* is used (the one which is set, not the one set by animation in hold). Try if it works. If it doesn't, then use combination of stop/hold - enter action animation holds its animation, while exit does stop.

Comment: Neither specifiying `To` nor `By` in the `ExitActions` did the trick. Thank you - this was way easier, than expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Sinatr in the comments, it is sufficient to just define `<DoubleAnimation>` (skipping the `By="-5"`) in the `ExitActions`. This will default to the initial value, not the one that is currently used in the animation.