# Binding a Storyboard Animation inside a DataTrigger crashes the XamlParser

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, storyboard, datatrigger

I want my application to animate an ellipse to a new position everytime a certain event happens. For testing purposes I made a button that changes a viewmodel property and this property is bound to a datatrigger that fires the animation, but later on I want the viewmodel to trigger it based on other events I haven't implemented yet - that's why I can't use the eventtrigger being bound to that button directly in the view, I need the viewmodel.
Because the ellipse is supposed to be moved by the animation to a new position everytime it gets fired, I need to bind the TO-Property of the DoubleAnimation to a value in the viewmodel. This works fine when I use a normal eventtrigger, but using the datatrigger crashes the XamlParser with that binding. I don't get any specific error except for an XAMLParseException, however, if I change the binding to a fixed value, for example 5, it'll work fine.

Here's the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="AnimationExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnimationExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Canvas Name="CanvasWrapper" Width="525" Height="350">
        <Button Content="Next Animation" Command="{Binding NextAnimation}"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="60" Height="60" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="60">
            <Ellipse.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanAnimate}" Value="True" >
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard >
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!-- Works fine without the binding -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                            Duration="0:0:10" To="{Binding NextPosX}" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Ellipse.Style>
        </Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

I believe that the parser is unable to find the correct path to the binding, even though the code completion shows it. Is there even a way I can get the correct path to the binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section [Data Binding and Animating Animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752312(v=vs.100).aspx) : basically animations are created frozen (i.e. all of its properties are read-only and hence can't be modified), the animation has to be recreated to reflect on property changed notifications.

Have a look at this [blog entry](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tamir/2007/03/19/how-to-bind-to-animation-to-and-from-properties/) and at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186933/wpf-animation-binding-to-the-to-attribute-of-storyboard-animation) SOF question.

Update based on your comment:

**First why DataTrigger and StoryBoard binding does not work?**

> The answer is provided by [Storyboards Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms742868(v=vs.85).aspx) as follows:
>
> You can't use dynamic resource references or data binding expressions
>   to set Storyboard or animation property values. That's because
>   everything inside a Style must be thread-safe, and the timing system
>   must Freeze Storyboard objects to make them thread-safe. A Storyboard
>   cannot be frozen if it or its child timelines contain dynamic resource
>   references or data binding expressions. For more information about
>   freezing and other Freezable features, see the Freezable Objects
>   Overview.

**Why binding work with EventTrigger but not with DataTrigger?**

Again from the same source:

> Animations applied by property Trigger objects behave in a more
>   complex fashion than EventTrigger animations or animations started
>   using Storyboard methods. They "handoff" with animations defined by
>   other Trigger objects, but compose with EventTrigger and
>   method-triggered animations.

I will **assume** that what they mean is that with EventTriggers the StoryBoard is recreated at the time of the event, but this is not the case with DataTriggers - "handoff" seems to imply Sharing of the StoryBoard. I will create a SO question to verify what is meant by this (question created here: [Storyboard: EventTrigger vs DataTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265487/storyboard-eventtrigger-vs-datatrigger) ).

Comment: Thank you. But if animations are read only, how is it possible that I was able to bind the exact same storyboard inside an event trigger? It even worked after I changed the value and played the animation to the new position. The app doesn't compile since I switched from eventtrigger to a data trigger.