# Custom ColorAnimation in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

So I have a large number of styles and control templates in a resource dictionary, some of these styles have storyboards with color animations. The problem was that I need to bind the "To" property of those color animations to whatever color the user had picked, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186933/wpf-animation-binding-to-the-to-attribute-of-storyboard-animation) helped me with that part of the problem. The only issue with that solution was that it was only a replacement for a double animations.

I tried making my own color animation with the following code:

```
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0,0,0));
if (values[1] is string && values[2] is string && values[0] is double)
{
     System.Drawing.Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(values[1].ToString());
     double r = System.Convert.ToInt16(color.R);
     double g = System.Convert.ToInt16(color.G);
     double b = System.Convert.ToInt16(color.B);
     System.Drawing.Color color2 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(values[2].ToString());
     double r2 = System.Convert.ToInt16(color2.R);
     double g2 = System.Convert.ToInt16(color2.G);
     double b2 = System.Convert.ToInt16(color2.B);
     int r3 = System.Convert.ToInt32(r + ((r2 - r) * (double)values[0]));
     int g3 = System.Convert.ToInt32(g + ((g2 - g) * (double)values[0]));
     int b3 = System.Convert.ToInt32(b + ((b2 - b) * (double)values[0]));
     brush = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(System.Convert.ToByte(r3), System.Convert.ToByte(g3), System.Convert.ToByte(b3)));
}
            
return brush;
```

But this doesn't look as good as the color animation from wpf, so I'm asking if there is a better way to do what I am doing, and if not how do I make my color animation more like wpf's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extend `ColorAnimation` to keep the default animation behavior or implementation details in general.

For example, create a `DynamicColorAnimation` class that extends `ColorAnimation` and define binding properties on it. The point is that you can't set `Binding` expressions inside a `Storyboard` as this would prevent the `Freezable` (in this case the `ColorAnimation`) from being frozen. To solve this, you can just collect the actual `Binding` values and then resolve them explicitly during runtime.

The behavior is similar to the e.g. `DataGridBoundColumn.Binding` property (for example of the extended `DataGridTextColumn`).
In our case we have two such binding properties named `FromBinding` and `ToBinding`. And because we won't define those properties as dependency properties, the `Freezable` will ignore the `Binding` values (allowing the `DynamicColorAnimation` to be frozen as required): the `Binding` in this case is not evaluated by the dependency property system and is instead treated like an ordinary property value.

If `DynamicColorAnimation.FromBinding` or `DynamicColorAnimation.ToBinding` is not set, the `DynamicColorAnimation` behaves like a normal `ColorAnimation` and falls back to the `ColorAnimation.From` or `ColorAnimation.To` property values.
`ColorAnimation.From` and `ColorAnimation.To` have precedence over `DynamicColorAnimation.FromBinding` and `DynamicColorAnimation.ToBinding`.
Both can be mixed, for example `FromBindng` and `To`.

```cs
public class DynamicColorAnimation : ColorAnimation
{
  // Helper class to resolve bindings
  internal class BindingResolver<TValue> : DependencyObject
  {
    // Define property of type 'object' to make it nullable by default.
    // Introduces boxing in case 'TValue' is a 'ValueType'.
    public object ResolvedBindingValue
    {
      get => (object)GetValue(ResolvedBindingValueProperty);
      set => SetValue(ResolvedBindingValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResolvedBindingValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ResolvedBindingValue",
      typeof(object),
      typeof(BindingResolver<TValue>),
      new PropertyMetadata(default));

    // Returns 'false' when the binding couldn't be resolved
    public bool TryResolveBinding(BindingBase bindingBase, out TValue? resolvedBindingValue)
    {
      _ = BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ResolvedBindingValueProperty, bindingBase);
      resolvedBindingValue = (TValue)this.ResolvedBindingValue;

      return this.ResolvedBindingValue is not null;
    }
  }

  public BindingBase? FromBinding { get; set; }
  public BindingBase? ToBinding { get; set; }
  private BindingResolver<Color> BindingValueProvider { get; }

  public DynamicColorAnimation()
  {
    this.BindingValueProvider = new BindingResolver<Color>();
  }

  // Because we extend ColorAnimation which is a Freezable, 
  // we must override Freezable.CreateInstanceCore too
  protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    => new DynamicColorAnimation();

  protected override Color GetCurrentValueCore(Color defaultOriginValue, Color defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
  {
    Color fromColor = this.From ?? defaultOriginValue;
    Color toColor = this.To ?? defaultDestinationValue;

    if (!this.From.HasValue
      && this.FromBinding is not null)
    {
      // Ignore the default value to give the defaultOriginValue 
      // parameter precedence in case the binding didn't resolve
      if (this.BindingValueProvider.TryResolveBinding(this.FromBinding, out Color bindingValue))
      {
        fromColor = bindingValue;
      }
    }

    if (!this.To.HasValue
      && this.ToBinding is not null)
    {
      // Ignore the default value to give the defaultOriginValue 
      // parameter precedence in case the binding didn't resolve
      if (this.BindingValueProvider.TryResolveBinding(this.ToBinding, out Color bindingValue))
      {
        toColor = bindingValue;
      }
    }

    return base.GetCurrentValueCore(fromColor, toColor, animationClock);
  }
}
```

### Usage Example

```xml
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"
       TargetType="Button">
  <Style.Resources>

    <!-- Some dynamic resources -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FromColor"
                     Color="DarkRed" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToColor"
                     Color="Orange" />
  </Style.Resources>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseMove">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>

          <!-- This example binds to the dynamic SolidColorBrush resources. 
               Of course, the bindings can use anything as source as usual -->
          <DynamicColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                 Duration="0:0:5"
                                 FillBehavior="Stop"
                                 FromBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource FromColor}, Path=Color}"
                                 ToBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource ToColor}, Path=Color}">
          </local:DynamicColorAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```