A VisualStateManager in a style template doesn't allow for a TemplateBinding
I am creating a style for a button so that I can easily control what color it is when I hover or click it. When I first started creating this I was using normal triggers, but this didn't work because I couldn't have an animation for clicking it. I was told to use a VisualStateManager instead. That was in this question
This has worked amazingly so far, but now I'm trying to create a custom button where I can control what color it is when hovering your mouse over it or when you click it. I have been trying to do this using a TemplateBinding, but this didn't work. So then I tried to use a RelativeSource where I set it to a TemplatedParent. This is a solution I found here. This for some reason didn't work and I'm very much stuck here.
This is my button class:
public class Button : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty HoverColorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        nameof(HoverColor),
        typeof(Color),
        typeof(Button),
        new PropertyMetadata());

    public Color HoverColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(HoverColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(HoverColorProperty, value);
    }
}

And here is my style
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Surface1Brush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BaseBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="HoverColor" Value="{DynamicResource Surface1Color}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:Button}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="4"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="MouseOver" To="Normal" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=HoverColor}" Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)}" Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


Do you get binding warnings in the output window about that binding?  If not, perhaps create a dummy value converter that does nothing but Debug.WriteLine the inputs and then just returns the given value as the output (thereby effectively doing nothing).  That would at least let you set a breakpoint and know when that binding is being invoked, examine the arguments, etc.

I don't think it's a good idea to call a custom control the same thing as another control. There's already a button. Don't call your not-a-button button.  When you have typeof(Button) then which does it pick?    If all you're adding is a dependency property then you should use an attached dependency property on a regular button imo.  Having said all that. Personally, I think I would define a colour as a resource rather than add a dependency property at all.  Usually, UX is consistent and rollover is same colour if you change colour on rollover.

@Joe I think I have figured out the issue. I think that the Visual State Manager decides what the color should be at compile time. So using a Visual State Manager wouldn't work no matter what I throw at it. So I will have to find another way to achieve this functionality.

@Andy I know that its not good practice to name things the same. The reason I chose to do it this way is because I think having "CustomButton" as an element inside my xaml code looks ugly. controls:Button already signals that its my own button through the namespace. It has its tradeoffs. I have a theme system to handle colors for me, I just do a DynamicBinding to get the color. The reason I want to do it using a template is so that I can have different color buttons without needing a lot of styles. I need a green button for the "Run Code" button and a red button for the "Exit" button.

As you noticed, animation's To propery is known to be unchangeable. You can find some of similar questions and workarounds such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186933/wpf-animation-binding-to-the-to-attribute-of-storyboard-animation/14164245
