# how to use Blend to set animation for expander

Tags: wpf, blend, expander

i try to use blend to design the UI of an application and want to use expander to create a menu, it is all done but i dont know how to set an animaiton for the expander, i want to slide down in, maybe 0.5s, and it expand in a function like quartic out. i can find some states if i create tamplate, but i tried all the states and they cant set the animation of expander.

hope someone who familiar Blend can help me, how to use blend to set expander an animation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRsjc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this before.  It's not something you can do easily in Blend unfortunately.  It involves some code.  See these:

[Animate Expander in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311637/animate-expander-in-wpf)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111586/How-to-create-an-animated-expander

Comment: thank you, i also found those before, also find that it is not easy to do animation using blend, already use code to create the animation but just want to know if, if there is possible to use blend to do  this work